# How does $xy - y = z + zx$ become $y (x - 1) = z (x + 1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Can anyone explain to me from where the $1$ and $1$ in $(5)$ came?

**Problem.** Make $y$ the subject of the formula 
$$x = \frac{y + z}{y - z}$$

**Solution:**

$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{y + z}{y - z} \tag{1} \\[4pt]
x (y - z) &= y + z \tag{2} \\[4pt]
xy - xz &= y + z \tag{3} \\[4pt]
xy - y &= z + zx \tag{4} \\[4pt]
y (x - 1) &= z (x + 1)\tag{5} \\[4pt]
y &= \frac{z(x + 1)}{x - 1}\tag{6}
\end{align}$$

---

What I have not understood is where the $y (x - 1) = z (x + 1)$ came.

Any help of tip is very appreciated.

Comment: Just factoring. $y(x-1)=xy-y$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can [factorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) since we have (Note the different colors):
$$x\color{red}{y}-\color{red}{y}=\color{green}{z}+x\color{green}{z}$$
Or, if you prefer:
$$x\color{red}{y}-1\color{red}{y}=1\color{green}{z}+x\color{green}{z}$$
Therefore:
$$\color{red}{y}(x-1)=\color{green}{z}(1+x)$$
Which is what the solution you provided suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $y$ is usually suppressed if it is $1$, so you can write $1\cdot y$ for $y$ if you need an explicit placeholder after factoring.

Thus, working with the left side of the equation, we have:
$$x\cdot y -y\tag{Given}$$
$$x\cdot y - 1\cdot y\tag{Write suppressed coefficient}$$
$$(x - 1)\cdot y\tag{Factor $y$ from the right}$$
$$y\cdot (x-1)\tag{Swap order of multiplication}$$
and similarly for the other side of the equation